# How to apply a specific style to an invalid field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Suppose I have a field like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="fullname" asp-for="UserName">Username</label>
<input class="form-control"
       type="text" name="username"
       required asp-for="UserName">
<span asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>
</div>
```

inside my controller I added this error:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("username", "username already registered");
```

Now, I want apply the focus on the `input` field and also I want apply a red border, is possible do this only via `MVC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the model validation fails and you return to the same view, the framework will add the `input-validation-error` CSS class to the input elements, for which the validation failed. In your case, you are adding the error message to the `UserName` field, so your `UserName` field input will get this new CSS class.

```
<input class="form-control input-validation-error" type="text" name="username" 
                           required="" id="UserName" value="some value">
```

You can add any sort of styling you want to this CSS class as needed.

```
.input-validation-error
{
    border-color:red;
}
```

Now setting the focus on a specific input field is a little tricky. The server code cannot do that. You have to do that on client side. But if there are multiple fields in the form with failed validation, which one you want to focus ? The first one, second one ? last one ?

Here is a quick sample to focus on the first input element with `input-validation-error` CSS class. The JavaScript code is executed on the jquery `document.ready` event.

```
$(function () {
    $("input.input-validation-error").first().focus();
});
```

If you want to style the validation error message rendered by the validation helper (`<span asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>`), follow the same approach. When validation fails, the framework will change the CSS class of this span element to `field-validation-error` (from `field-validation-valid`). So all you have to do is, add the needed style definitions to that CSS class.

```
.field-validation-error
{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: ok so I guess there is no built in way to do this, just a workaround?

Comment: For the focus, Yes.

Comment: just an ot question: if I use `<span asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>` how can I display the text red?